# Can't run Raspbian container on docker

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, raspbian, hypriot

So I've installed the [hypriot OS](https://blog.hypriot.com/getting-started-with-docker-on-your-arm-device/) for docker and I have tested it with `ocker run -d -p 80:80 hypriot/rpi-busybox-httpd`. All is well and the test works.

However, when I run `docker run -i -t resin/rpi-raspbian` to get raspbian nothing happens and `docker ps` shows no containers running. There are no error messages.

What is happening to my raspbian container?

Thanks

Comment: What's the `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` values in the `resin/rpi-raspbian` image? Whatever's being run is exiting after executing. `docker ps -a` should show it.

Answer (score 0):

Running on Mac OSX and having downloaded the resin/rpi-raspbian image, I issue the command:

```
docker run -i -t resin/rpi-raspbian /bin/bash
```

which starts the container and puts me at the command prompt in raspbian.